# docxtpl returning value error for dictionary

Tags: python, python-docx

Hi I'm using the docxtpl module to create new docx files containing some web scraped info however when I try to run my code I get a value error. This is the portion of the code of interest. The error seems to be with the render context line

```
doc = DocxTemplate('template1.docx')
context = {
            f'Title: {opptitle}'
            f'Dates - '
            f'Published: {published} '
          f'Deadline for Questions: {questions_deadline} '
          f'Closing Date: {closing} '
          f'About: {summary}'
          f'Why the work is being done: {purpose}'
          f'Problem to be Solved: {problem}'
          f'Skills & Experience: {skills_exp}'
    }
    doc.render(context)
    doc.save("generated_doc.docx")
```

I can't quite figure out the solution. The same information rendered to a .txt file just fine so the values such as {summary} are ok, but I'm trying to render to a word file. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: show the exact error with full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

your code is little weird for me,
because i usually write f-string method in dictionary elements as.

```
{'key':f'{elements}'}
```

Also i use docxtpl like

```
subject_idx = 0
# df1: pandas dataframe
context = {
    "name" : f"{df1.index[subject_idx]}", 
    "o_o" : f"{df1.iloc[subject_idx, 0]}"
}
```

it works well for me,